# Jest testing API Expect 200 but received 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

Hi I am testing to see if it authorizes me to get orders. Currently BeforeAll is reading the token but I still receive 401 when I run my test. What is going wrong in my code? I am using Jest and Supertest.

This is my test file.

```
import app from '../server' 
import request from 'supertest'
jest.useFakeTimers()

let token 

beforeAll((done) => {
    request(app)
        .post('/api/users/login')
        .send({
            email: 'test15@email.com',
            password: '123456'
        })
        .end((err, response) => {
            token = response.body.token; // saving token 
            done();
        });
});


describe('app', () => {

    describe('Statuses', () => {
        it('Index should return 200 Status', () => {
           return request(app)
                .get('/api/orders')
                .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
                .then((response) => {
                 expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
                })
        });
    }); 
});
```

I save the token beforehand then I run my test. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find a solution.

auth.js

```
const protect = asyncHandler(async(req,res,next) => {
    let token 
    if(
        req.headers.authorization && 
        req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
    ){
        console.log('token found')
    }{
        try {
            token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
            req.user= await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')

            next()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            res.status(401)
            throw new Error('Not authorized, token failed')
        }
    }

    if (!token){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('Not Authorized, no token')
    }
})
```

Comment: Why it should return http status 200?

Comment: @hoangdv 401 is unauthorized and 200 is ok

Comment: Your server requires an access token to access to `/api/orders` resource.

Comment: Well, I am currently returning a token. BeforeAll is returning a token and saving it to the variable token. I then use it in my unit test  and call token again with Bearer but it still fails

Comment: Are you sure `token` variable has value?

Comment: Well I know for sure there is a value in the BeforeAll but I am not sure if my test is reading that value. I can see its returning a string in this format string.string.string.

Comment: How your server validate access token?

Comment: @hoangdv I posted it at the end of the question the formatting looked weird. But here is how I validate the token It is the auth.js file

Comment: See the log of the server when you run the test.

Comment: So the token is found but after it's found nothing else seems to show up. I am assuming it's not being read in that case.

Comment: `}{` you mean `else {` ?

Comment: Else as in the console log. The console log nothing just shows token found but it won't log anything past that if that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

As long as you only need to test if response is ok, instead of using Jest `expect`, did you try using the `expect` from `superset`? something like:

```
it('should return 200 Status', () => {
  request(app)
    .get('/api/orders')
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    .expect(200, done);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I did unfortunately it still gives me the same error